# Custom Message on VBA Debug Error

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-2010, vba

I have a macro that automatically saves a file to several shared locations.  If a user has a file open at one of the locations, the macro will debug becuase it cannot overwrite the open file.

What I want to do display a custom error message that says "The file is currently in use by another user" instead of the generic debug message.  Each save operation has its own segment of code, so I can know which file location is open by where the code breaks.

Is there a way to use error handling to display this type of custom message?

I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: I would check to see if the files are open before trying to open them. If they are open, display the message and exit the code. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291295) is a MS KB article on how to check if the file is open.

Comment: +1 great article find @Adach1979

Comment: Adach1979 - THANK YOU.  This article is exactly what I'm looking for.  If you post your comment as an answer I mark it as the correct one. Much appreciated!